MAMP for WIndows: PHP version drop down selection is only showing v8.2.14 and v.8.3.1, no way to go lower than 5.6
I hope someone here can help me out. I'm currently running MAMP Version: 5.0.6 (7029) x64 binaries release (not PRO) and Windows 10. I have a migration project that I need to run old PHP codes under v5.6, and I wanted to do it first in my local laptop.
When I checked the PHP version drop down list at MAMP control panel, it's only showing v8.2.14 and v.8.3.1.
Current MAMP PHP Version Dropdown selection
I have \MAMP\bin\php\php5.6.34 in my laptop, and ran <?php phpinfo(); ?> , it showed that active php.ini is in \MAMP\conf\php8.3.1\php.ini.
This question has been closed as it was tagged that it's been resolved already here: How can I add additional PHP versions to MAMP, but the question was originally asked way back 2013, and in order for me to even to contribute to that question is I need 50 reputation points.
I tried following the suggestion from that question.

Renaming the versions that I don't need at \MAMP\bin\php\
Current \MAMP\bin\php\ directory -> Not working

I got lost in how to add PHP v5.6 to it (I'm aware that each versions has their separate php.ini files, but I'm scared of breaking things at the moment as I have another project that requires the latest PHP version.
Is there anyone here knows how to add an older version of PHP to the MAMP control panel drop down list?
